# cakephp 3.0 upgrade tool - Trouble understanding docs - Install tool where - folder to upgrade - where?

Tags: upgrade, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to convert 100 models + several hundred controllers & views from cakephp 2.6.7 to cakephp 3.0.7.

I've tried the following with the upgrade shell tool:

- download the zip file
- place into project main folder (i.e. same folder that cake 2.6.7 app resides)
- php composer.phar install
- composer upgrade all.  This installs all of cakePHP 3.0
- Then the docs leave me with lots of questions...

  The upgrade tool provides a standalone application that can be used to upgrade other applications or cakephp plugins. Each of the subcommands accepts a path that points to the application you want to upgrade.

  cd /path/to/upgrade

  bin/cake upgrade all /home/mark/Sites/my-app

  bin/cake upgrade skeleton /home/mark/Sites/my-app

  bin/cake upgrade locations [path]

  bin/cake upgrade namespaces [path]

  bin/cake upgrade app_uses [path]

First... I'm already in E:\my-app    !

Second...  After running a "cake upgrade locations E:\my-app" (the first task command)  Nothing is modified and no files are moved.  In fact if I run each of the commands listed in the documentation and never use the "all" command, the \src folder is almost empty.  It does contain a Templates folder!

The \app folder still has all the Controllers, Views, Models.

There are not Tables, Entities, etc.

I could use a little hint as to what I need to see differently.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a solution, but I add to link questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31246623/cakephp-3-manual-installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, the upgrade shell is a standalone application, and you should install it separately, that is, in a separate folder (for example `E:\cakephp-upgrade\`), *not* in your project folder! Also when using the `all` command, it should not be necessary to run the individual commands again, it would render the `all` command pretty useless if you'd have to do that.

That being said, the problem with the non-moved files stems from two issues

1. The path passed to the upgrade shell must end with a directory separator, otherwise the shell will use double separators at some point, because a separator is left in the path [**when the root is being stripped from it**](https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade/blob/cafe211ea14ea00a69b754e44581b1fde820912e/src/Shell/Task/LocationsTask.php#L140) (**https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade/issues/89**).
2. When not using GIT, and files need to be moved as well as changed, then the files are not being written to the proper target path, [**but to the source path**](https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade/blob/cafe211ea14ea00a69b754e44581b1fde820912e/src/Shell/Task/StageTask.php#L209) (**https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade/issues/90**).

<strike>Please [**report this as an issue**](https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade) over at GitHub.</strike>

Unfortuantely the GIT usage seems to be buggy too (**https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade/issues/88**), but I'm too lazy to trace this down right now. So until this is all fixed, you should be able workaround these issues by running *all* the commands manually, that way the files are being moved first, which seems to work fine.

So, assuming that the upgrade app is installed in `E:\cakephp-upgrade\`, and your project is in `E:\my-app`, then you'd do

```
E:
cd cakephp-upgrade
bin\cake upgrade locations E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade namespaces E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade app_uses E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade rename_classes E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade rename_collections E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade method_names E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade method_signatures E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade fixtures E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade tests E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade i18n E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade prefixed_templates E:\my-app\
bin\cake upgrade skeleton E:\my-app\
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, it is very informative, but I did find these answers on a blog by mark story.  At this point I'm doing a conversion without the upgrade shell... it will be my last!