# git issue with cakephp3 upgrade tool on wamp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I cant get the upgrade cakephp3 tool to run properly on my wamp64, win7 pc.
After installing the upgrade tool from git l check it is installed with bin\cake upgrade --help.   I then run the below commands.

```
D:
cd wamp64\www\upgrade-master
bin\cake upgrade locations ..\my-app\   <seems to work and no error output>
bin\cake upgrade namespaces ..\my-app\   <error here! as I get git is not recognizable output>
```

I dont see this 'git' issue in the docs so I dont know what to do. Then if this does work what do I do then because the docs finish.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/upgrade-tool.html

[cakephp 3.0 upgrade tool - Trouble understanding docs - Install tool where - folder to upgrade - where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214440/cakephp-3-0-upgrade-tool-trouble-understanding-docs-install-tool-where-fol)

Comment: Please do not paraphrase error messages, show the exact output.

Comment: i downloaded git for windows and I dont get this error anymore. I am not clear on how to use the upgrade tool. Do I just changes locations and namespaces as the docs say?

Comment: If you've got a new question - either re-purpose this (unclear, would get closed) question or ask a new question. Do not use comments to ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded git for windows ,  installed it and viewed files from my c drive to test to see if i works.  I dont get this error anymore.