# How do I upgrade version of cakephp2.0 to cakephp3 and cakephp4 step by step?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

According to the topic, I want to upgrade the cakephp2.0 version to next cakehp3.0 version.

Change version as soon as possible. I have tried but there were change all the files of project and this project was coded in cakephp2.0 version and not upgraded.

Comment: How to upgrade projects from CakePHP 2 has been covered here many times in the past. In short, there's a tool that can do some of the work for you (renaming files, updating namespaces, etc.), but the bulk of the changes (e.g. converting to the new ORM) are going to need manual work, and depending on the size of the project you might just be better off rewriting it. Also, note that CakePHP is now on version 4.4, and v5 is pending, so if you're going to start from scratch, v3 is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: Like Greg has said, this is a hard pill to swallow and like yourself, me currently on CakePHP 2.10.x / 2.x after going thru countless blogs, IRCs and forums. CP 2.x was considered the frankenstein / young-teen like version of CP where a lot of different practices was removed and or streamed lined some in 3.x and a complete overhaul in CP 4.x . What I have gathered is a rebuild is inevitable from 2.x to 4.x (bypassing 3.x) . The upgrade ability was not a sure cut and dry option and you will possibly be creating more work then you already have in the learning curve. Good Luck to Both of us.

Comment: There's always the [3-0-migration-guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html). Maybe see [cakephp 3.0 upgrade tool - Trouble understanding docs - Install tool where - folder to upgrade - where?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31214440/)